# If the derivative of a function is bijective, is the function itself bijective as well?

Tags: real-analysis

Or the inverse: Is it possible for a function to  exist whose derivative is bijective, but is not bijective itself?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider $f(x)= x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the title question is "no."

Consider $f(x)=x^2$.

Is it bijective?

What is its derivative, and is that bijective?

Comment: In hindsight this was very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

No (respectively, "yes"). In fact, if the image of the derivative contains a neighbourhood of $0$, then the function is not injective.